# Twitter Bootstrap - Spans refuse to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10, html

Just getting started with twitter bootstrap. Awesome so far until I've come across something I just cannot get to work.

Basically I'm trying to do a simple left side nav bar/column with a content area on the right. According to everything I've found I should be able to do the following with a "span2" and "span10" pair of div tags inside a "row" div.

However, everything I try the spans always stretch 100% of the width available and then the next span will slot below in a new line.

The bootstrap CSS is working... I can make responsive nav-bars and all sorts. Just this span situation fails me.

Is there something missing from this? At its most simple implementation?

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">Nav bar</div>
        <div class="span10">Content</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For the record, I'm building this in ASP.Net and IE10.

Thanks,
Nay.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using bootstrap 2 or twb3 ?

Comment: It was bootstrap 3, and I found the answer in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nice Question Nay;

Bootstrap3 differs from Bootstrap2.

Try changing the **span** to **col-md-*** ( or col-xs )

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Nav bar</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">Content</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

This blog helped me understand in more detail http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that you are using Bootstrap 2. A simple layout would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>Stuff</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>stuff</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The container centers the page, the row wraps around the columns (i.e. spans) and the `well` classes are just placeholders. You just need to remember that columns should always be wrapper in a row (as illustrated above).

If you want some responsiveness, you can add the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file. Also, make sure to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>` so that the responsiveness take effect on devices.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Found an answer...

It appears bootstrap 2.x and 3.0 have a number of changes that I was not aware about. I believe I just need to go through and change my code.

span* is now col-md-*, etc.

Just after I give up and post a question, I find the problem... :/

Comment: Oh, an being a new, low-rep user, I couldn't reply to my own comment to close it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try making the maximum count of the span to 11.

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">Nav bar</div>
        <div class="span9">Content</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

User this and it will work.

I had the same problem if I use total span of 12. But it works for 11